# Como transformar um Cursor em uma String?

Tags: android, sqlite

Olá, eu preciso descobrir como transformar um Cursor com dados vindos do Banco de Dados Interno do Android (SQLite) em uma Array de String ou String.

Já tentei de algumas formas, mas nenhuma resultou em nada.

```
String lista = "Lista de Compras \n\n";
for (int i = 0; i <= cursor.getColumnCount(); i++){
    lista.concat(cursor.getString(i)+ "\n");
}
```

E no Banco de Dados:

```
public Cursor buscaListaProdutos(){
    SQLiteDatabase banco = getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = banco.rawQuery("SELECT _id, nomeProduto, qtdeProduto FROM listaProduto", null);

    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        banco.close();
        return c;
    }else{
        banco.close();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Você precisa fazer isso manualmente ou arrumar um ORM que faça isso por você. Este tipo de operação não se faz de forma tão simples ou nativa.

Comment: Amigo é muito simples.. veja esse post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354006/how-can-i-create-a-list-array-with-the-cursor-data-in-android